# route config not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

i'm new with asp.net mvc and have an issue with routing. 
i'm trying to modify the following url -

```
localhost:2124/Teum/ClosedEvents
```

into

```
localhost:2124/Teum/history
```

by using routing as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "history",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Teum", action = "ClosedEvents", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

i saw here one solution with Web.config and add to it

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

but it is still don't work, either way i'm getting 404 error.

will appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: the actionResult is ClosedEvents but i want it to display in url as history

Answer (score 3):

To "rename" the `ClosedEvents` action to `history`, you need to make the `{action}` URL segment literal.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "history",
    url: "Teum/History",
    defaults: new { controller = "Teum", action = "ClosedEvents" }
);
```

You don't necessarily need to make `{controller}` into a parameter, but may be helpful if your goal is to rename this action on several different controllers. You also may not need the optional `{id}` parameter, but this is how you would add it if you wanted one.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "history",
    url: "Teum/History/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Teum", action = "ClosedEvents", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you want "history" to be lowercase, you should use

```
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
```

at the top of your `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes()` method. Otherwise, case sensitivity doesn't matter in the routing configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Your rouging should be like this :

**First you have to add IgnoreRoute:**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
{ 
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


    routes.MapRoute("history", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                     new { controller = "Teum", action = "ClosedEvents", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                );
 }
```

**And your *Global.asax* File :**

```
protected void Application_Start() 
{ 

RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

If you have multiple parameter in your Controller action then routing should be :

```
//Action With Parameter 
public ActionResult ClosedEvents(string searchBy, string search, int page = 1, int pageSize = 20, bool falsPositive = false) 
{ 
}


//And your routing should be :
routes.MapRoute( 
"history", // Route name 
"{controller}/{action}/{searchBy}/{search}/{page}/{pageSize}/{falsPositive}", // URL with parameters 
new { controller = "Teum", action = "ClosedEvents", searchBy = "", search = "",page="",pageSize="",falsPositive="" } // Parameter defaults 
);
```

Cheers !!

Comment: i dont want it to be the default page, just want to rename it on display but not in action name, i understood it is possible but dont know how to apply it.

Comment: Change default name to 'history'

Comment: i did it, take another look on the question

Comment: doesn't matter since no id is passing into the action

Comment: you have this : public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"); in your routhconfig file check updated ans

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149310/discussion-between-laxman-gite-and-tzahi-kadosh).